# Global Injectivity Criterion of Meromorphic Functions

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, singularity, meromorphic-functions

Suppose we have a locally injective meromorphic function $f$ on some domain $D$.  The three interesting cases for $D$ are the plane, the disc and an arbitrary domain.  Suppose its poles are $P = \lbrace p_1, \dots, p_n \rbrace$ (assumed finite).

Question: Is there a tree contained in $D$ with endpoints $P$ on which $f$ is injective, aside from (possibly) the poles themselves?

Comment: Why do you think the tag "algebraic-topology" is relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D$ is a disk, it is not true, see the picture ($f$ exists by the Riemann mapping theorem). Not sure about the case when $D$ is the entire plane.

[image: picture]